# Difference between struct and class in Common Lisp

Tags: class, struct, common-lisp, clos

My understanding of a struct is that it has slots to store data in, has a type, has `make-X` and slot-accessor functions, and can be specialized on by a method (since it has a type).

My understanding of a class is that it has all of the same and multiple inheritance. The top answer to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4546118/whats-the-idiomatic-equivalent-of-c-structs-in-lisp) states that structs can have single inheritance, and that initial implementations of CLOS were "much slower" than structs.

Based on how people talk about CLOS and structs, I assume there must be some other differences, but my trivial google searches have been fruitless. So I ask: what are the practical differences between CLOS and structs?

Answer (score 28, accepted):

**Structures**

[Structures](http://www.lispworks.com/documentation/HyperSpec/Body/08_.htm) are more primitive. They provide what often is called a *record* in programming languages. They were introduced in Common Lisp before classes. CLtL1 (the first book describing Common Lisp) in 1984 already had structures and later a standard object system called CLOS was added. Structures provide

- a concise definition macro `DEFSTRUCT`
- single inheritance
- fast slot access
- defines reader and setf access for slots
- defines a type predicate
- defines a constructor function
- defines a copy function
- a printed representation: structures can be read and printed
- above functions maybe inlined

useful additions:

- DEFSTRUCT can define list- and vector-based representations of structures, in addition to structure types

Limitations:

- after a change to a structure type, structure instances are not updated
- if a structure type is changed, it is best to recompile and re-run changed code. Maybe restart the program. The effects of redefining a structure are undefined in standard Common Lisp.
- very little introspection: portable Common Lisp does not tell me super/sub-structures of a structure in an easy way. portable Common Lisp does not tell me the slots of a structure.
- no slot access via slot names by default

Extensions

- some implementations provide more runtime introspection and a little bit integration in some CLOS functions

**CLOS classes**

[CLOS](http://www.lispworks.com/documentation/HyperSpec/Body/07_.htm) was invented in the mid/late 80s based on two earlier object systems (Flavors and LOOPS). It provides:

- a defining macro `DEFCLASS`
- multiple inheritance
- protocols for creation, initialization, etc.
- CLOS objects can be changed and updated at runtime based on class changes (new slots, redefined slots, removed slots, changed inheritance, ...)
- CLOS objects can change their class and be updated at runtime
- access via slot names possible

limitations:

- no default printer/reader
- `DEFCLASS` definitions are not very concise

extensions

- faster slot access by added implementation specific functionality
- Meta-Object Protocol provides added functionality and flexibility: introspection and reflection. Sometimes only parts of the MOP are provided.
- user-provided extensions are available, especially for implementations with MOP support

**Common Lisp**

In some cases the Common Lisp standard does not say how a functionality should be implemented: structures, classes, or maybe even something else. Examples are streams and conditions. It's usually a good sign (for added flexibility) if a Common Lisp implementation uses CLOS for those.

Comment: Out of curiosity, how does one test whether an implementation uses CLOS for (for example) streams?

Comment: @Reepca: if a type is a subtype of `standard-object`, then it is a CLOS class. For a condition type: `(subtypep 'error 'standard-object)` -> T or NIL . Some implementations may allow, for example, various CLOS and non-CLOS types of streams.

Comment: Could you elaborate on how changing classes at runtime is useful? I can't think of other languages that really have this so I never thought in those terms.

Comment: @MasterMastic: change as in changing an object so that it is an instance of a different class? a) Think of anything long-running which you want to update: either in the development environment or an application. You may have a Lisp application for which you want to load a software patch without killing the application. b) a typical simple thing would be to change an object to a more special class once the application knows more about the thing. Oh, the TCP stream is actually a POP3 stream... change the stream instance to a pop3 stream class.

Comment: Oh I see. I was talking about changing the class. As for the latter, it's common for any language, isn't it? e.g. a TCP -> POP3 function. As for the former, I think I would be hesitant to patch classes, it's probably not very good for the codebase, right? but I bet that's its own discussion. Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 4):

[`defstruct`](http://clhs.lisp.se/Body/m_defstr.htm) does more work for you behind the scenes, e.g.:

1. defines slot accessors automatically
2. defines readable [`print-object`](http://clhs.lisp.se/Body/f_pr_obj.htm) method

Also, structure slot access is faster (although the difference is probably inconsequential).

The bottom line is that, unless you need MOPish features, you can get away with `defsrtuct`.